# Readability program for text

Tags: floating-point, readability

The program below will use a formula to calculate the grade of every text input. It will use a formula to correlate the number of letters,words and senteces to print a grade.
I am getting floating point exception and I can´t fix it. Please help.
Thanks

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Type your text: ");
    int i;
    int num_letters = 0;
    int num_words = 0;
    int num_sentences = 0;

// iterates trhough the text and compares to the defined functions in ctype
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++ )
    {

        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            num_letters++;
        }

        if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            num_words++;
        }

        if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            num_sentences++;
        }

    }
    printf("letters: %i; words: %i; sentences: %i\n", num_letters, num_words, num_sentences);

    float L = (num_letters / num_words) * 100;
    float S = (num_sentences / num_words) * 100;
    float grade = (0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S) - 15.8;
    int total = round(grade);
        {
            if (total >= 16 )
            {
                printf ("Grade 16+\n");
            }

            if (total < 1)
            {
                printf ("Grade less than 1\n");
            }

            else
            {
                printf ("Grade: %i\n", total);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception exactly? Did you try to debug to see at what point it occurs?

Comment: It gets the exception on float L. arithmetic exception

Comment: What is the value of num_words when the calculation takes place?

Comment: number of words is not correct. gives one less. for the sentence: One fish. Two fish. Red fish. Blue fish. - output is letters: 29; words: 7; sentences: 4

Comment: can you please add this last information in your question and explain on which statement you obtain an exception. Can you give input that return exception or better; replace input by a constant string that produce this error ?